# EF 4.1 Code First - storing Images in Firebird database

Tags: mapping, entity-framework-4.1, firebird, code-first

I'm trying to store images in Firebird database using blobs. In my class I've declared them as byte[]:

```
[Column("SMALLIMAGE")]
public Byte[] SmallImage { get; set; }
[Column("MEDIUMIMAGE")]
public Byte[] MediumImage { get; set; }
[Column("BIGIMAGE")]
public Byte[] BigImage { get; set; }
```

I'm getting DbUpdateException in SaveChanges(). How can I map Byte[] to BLOB in Firebird?

Regards, Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Firebird but if your database specific type is called BLOB you can try:

```
[Column("SMALLIMAGE", TypeName="BLOB")]
public Byte[] SmallImage { get; set; }
```

Or in fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityType>()
            .Property(e => e.SmallImage)
            .HasColumnName("SMALLIMAGE")
            .HasColumnType("BLOB");
```

Comment: The error message didn't changed - "Error at actualising items" (translated from german). And stack trace:  bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   bei System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: What is a normal way for firebird to store binary columns? This looks like BLOB is not supported.

Comment: CREATE TABLE BOOKS
(
  ID Integer NOT NULL,
  TITLE Varchar(1024),
  BINDING Varchar(40),
  ISBN Varchar(20),
  ASIN Varchar(20),
  SMALLIMAGE Blob sub_type 0,
  MEDIUMIMAGE Blob sub_type 0,
  BIGIMAGE Blob sub_type 0,
  NUMBEROFPAGES Integer NOT NULL,
  PUBLICATIONDATE Varchar(25),
  DETAILPAGEURL Varchar(1024),
  LANGUAGEORIGINAL Varchar(40),
  LANGUAGEPUBLISHED Varchar(40),
  SUBJECT Varchar(25),
  CLASS Integer NOT NULL,
  PUBLISHER_ID Integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);